# Asterisk: how test dial plan?

Tags: asterisk

I have the follow extension:

```
_[*#+0-9]./_014.,1,NoOp(_[*#+0-9]./_014. matches Rule rtg-Rotaoi-1)
```

It's generated by OpenVox Gateway, and he allways put _[*#+0-9] on begin of expression.

Then I tried to dial many numbers, what number, for ie, matches with this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression matches any number dialed, as long as the dialing caller ID starts with 014, and is of any length. Honestly, I have no idea why would anyone create such a dialplan rule - but again, I'm not familiar with your gateway.